# CxFreeze changes default encoding back to ascii

Tags: python, encoding, cx-freeze

When I run a script as is, and freezes it with cxFreze, I got encoding errors.  After looking into it, the problem is that cxFreeze seems to go back to the 'ascii' encoding, although Python uses 'utf-8' as default.

Here's the simple script that I use:

```
import sys
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Couldn't be shorter.  The setup.py file:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("test_encoding.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = 'test encoding',
    version = '0.1',
    description = "Nothing much...",
    executables = executables,
)
```

If I run it directly:

```
> python27 test_encoding.py
utf-8
```

But while frozen:

```
> build\exe.win32-2.7\test_encoding.exe
ascii
```

Does anyone know why it happens... and how to fix it?  As you can imagine, that creates lots of errors, particularly with wxPython.

Version information:

- Python: 2.7 (32-bit)
- Operating system: Windows 10 (64-bit)
- cx_Freeze: 4.3.4

Comment: What version of cx_Freeze are you using?

Comment: 4.3.4, sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7 the default encoding is ASCII so this is expected. You'll need to find out what is changing the default encoding to UTF-8 when running Python directly -- site defaults is a likely culprit.

Comment: Yes... it wouldn't surprise me much.  I looked into site.py though, and it seems to be ASCII, unless I change some default values that seem all to False by default.  I tried to look into lib/libs/include folders in python27, to see if I could find a setdefaultencoding... but out of unittests for Twisted and site.py itself, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit.  In my case, it was Evennia, that had a customsite.  For a reason I can't begin to understand, Python was looking for this file in my source folder.  I deleted the directory altogether and the problem is fixed.